# Paste event firing many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, errai

This is my code for Chrome to handle paste event:

```
window.addEventListener("paste",processEvent);
function processEvent(e) {      
       console.log("paste event!");
}
```

This code works fine except that the event is fired many times even if I press the `CTRL+V` command just once. What could be the reason? And how can I prevent this from happening as its very important that the handler to fire just once per press of the paste command.

**Update:**

I logged to the console and here is what I mean:

```
paste event!
clipboard from event
item found: 0 kind=file type=image/png
found image!
paste event!
clipboard from event
item found: 0 kind=file type=image/png
found image!
paste event!
clipboard from event
item found: 0 kind=file type=image/png
found image!
```

Notice how the same  event is fired 3 times.

**Update 2:**

This code is actually a GWT code wrapped around JSNI:

```
public native void pasteEventHandler()/*-{
    window.addEventListener("paste",processEvent);
    function processEvent(e) {      
           console.log("paste event!");
    }
}-*/;
```

And is called during [@PostConstruct](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Lifecycle+Tools) of the app:

```
@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
     pasteEventHandler();
}
```

When the paste event occurs the "page" with transition to another page (from #Page1 to #Page2. When the page transition back to #Page1, the setup() method is fired up.

Comment: When I say many times, I mean sometimes twice or three (3) times

Comment: Are you sure you only press once and you don't hold the paste shortcut (CTRL+V) down? Here i made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XFPkt/ and when i click on the result window (right under) and press ctrl+v i only get one message, unless i keep it pressed.

Comment: your braces markup is wrong buddy it seems

Comment: maybe you add your event listener multiple times for some reason...

Comment: Add another console line before you add the event listener. `console.log("adding event listener");window.addEventListener("paste",processEvent);` Do you see that console line show up 3 times? My magic ball is saying yes.

Comment: Judging from your extra `}` the code is inside a loop or a function, so most likely @epascarello is correct and you simply attach the event more than once.

Comment: Can you show us what code surrounds your event binding code?

Comment: @KevinB I have updated the question, although this is not pure Javascript (i.e. GWT/JSNI), the idea is still there.

Comment: Is it possible that `setup` is being executed more than once on your page?

Comment: @KevinB Actually yes, during page transition, going back to the "page" where this code reside, setup method is fired up, in the plain javascript, this means my app is creating multiple event listeners? right?

Comment: Correct. That would be why it's happening multiple times. You need to either unbind it, or stop binding it multiple times.

Comment: @KevinB thanks! problem solved, that PostConstuct is called many times, so I put the AfterInitialization annotation method which is called one time only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from your code I see additional `}`

```
window.addEventListener("paste",processEvent);
    function processEvent(e) {      
       console.log("paste event!");
    }
}  // what's that ?
```

Maybe that `}` belongs to a `for` or `while` (or whatever) iteration.

Comment: This question is answered by @KevinB